# Flutter: Date field onChange do not work when trying to NULL it out on first visit

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

```
               Expanded(
                  child: DateTimeInputWidget(
                    controller:
                        _controller.dateOfInvoiceFieldController,
                    labelText: "Invoice Date",
                    format: DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"),
                    onChanged: (selectedDate) {
                      setState(() {
                        print("selectedDate");
                        String s = selectedDate.toString().split(" ")[0];
                        print(s);
                        _controller.invoiceDate = s;
                        _controller.toggleInInvoice(
                          context,
                          (Function state) => this.setState(state),
                        );
                      });
                    }
                  ),
                ),
```

1. Above Custom Date Input field in flutter doesn't trigger **onChange** when I try to blank it out by clicking the cross (x) button next to the date.
2. But if I try to change the date to some other date then the **onChange** is triggered.
3. And after #2 is executed the cross(x) also works fine hence now successfully assigning NULL to the date (which is not the case on first visit to the screen)